# Upload json object as file stream in REST API in node JS

Tags: node.js, json, file-upload

I have JSON object which is really big, I would like to upload this object as JSON file through REST API.

I tried to write the json object in local file system then created read stream from the file and uploaded it. But I have a limitation that I shouldn't create a file locally, I would like to upload the json object directly to the REST api as like any other file.

Is it possible to send json object as stream into REST API

Answer (score 0):

Create a new BLOB with the JSON object that you want to send, and then use FormData to send it across as a file.

```
var formData = new FormData();
var blob = new Blob(['{"hello": "world!!!"}'], { type: 'text/json' });
formData.append('file', blob,'my_file.json');
```

And then send it across as a POST request.

```
fetch('http://URLgoesHere',
{ method: 'POST', body: formData,})
.then(console.log("works!"))
.catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

If you are trying to do this serverside, it's probably easier to just send the JSON object directly, and when received at client side, just create a blob with the JSON data and download it as a text file.