# How to upload 3000 list item using node web service?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to upload 3000 list item using Rest API. I am getting 413 response payload Too Large. Then I have divided list into multiple parts but how to upload parts one after another ?

Comment: use a blob (example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54559248/upload-json-object-as-file-stream-in-rest-api-in-node-js )you can use cross-blob package as well